# Play! Framework [1.2.4] - accepting audio/xwav Content-Type via wami-recorder

Tags: java, http, playframework

I am trying to record a sound snippet on the browser side with https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/, then upload that file via the wami example and a server-side controller method.  For some reason, the `request.body` `InputStream` is throwing this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:198)
    at controllers.APIVoicemailController.addNewRecording(APIVoicemailController.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:256)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:276)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

The controller method for route `POST /upload`

```
   public static void addNewRecording() {
        if (request.method.equals(Constants.METH_POST)) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = request.body;
                Map<String, Header> headerMap = request.headers;
                for (Entry<String, Header> entry : headerMap.entrySet()) {
                    Logger.info("Head: " + entry.getKey() + " name; "
                        + entry.getValue().name + " val: " + entry.getValue().value());
                }

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    "/Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/file.mp3"));

                int read = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                            /* ERROR ON LINE BELOW */
                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (Entry<String, String> params : request.params.allSimple().entrySet()) {
                Logger.info("k: " + params.getKey() + "v: " + params.getValue());
            }
            renderCustomMessage("Created new recording.", "Success.");
        }
    }
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Play 2, but if you just get the content of the `InputStream` without checking headers, you will be able to store it in WAV file or DB without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly the same lately.The steps followed are as follows:

1.Picked up the sample code for Wami which was posting to record.php

2.Changed the post url from record.php to the url corresponding to my controller in Play

3.Inside the controller,just saved the data received without checking for headers.(Probably this is the difference i saw in your code).
Using firebug may help you to see the request type(whether it is audio/.. or not)

The data was contained in the request body and just reading it as an input stream and writing it to a mp3 sufficed for me.